# Is there a JInterop replacement ?

Tags: j-interop

Beacause the JInterop follows GPL version 3, so we want to find anther one works just like it.

Inlcude commercial product. Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you try [j-integra (commercial)](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) or [Jacob (LGPL)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/).

PS: I only work with j-interop, so I could not say if one of them could really replace j-interop. Jacob I think works only on windows machines.